# JQuery tab clone not working

Tags: jquery, tabs, clone

I'm using Jquery tabs which work well. However, when I build one dynamically via JQuery clone, they don't seem to work.  The clone has generated correctly for the tab link and tab content.  My code below:

Generated HTML ('test' is the cloned tab)

```
<div class="tabcontainer jtabcontainer">
  <div class="tablink jtablink">
    <div class="tab jtab active">
      <a href="#headerone">HeaderOne</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab jtab">
      <a href="#test">test</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabsection jtabsection" id="headerone" style="display: block;" data-label="HeaderOne">blah blah</div>
  <div class="tabsection jtabsection" id="test" style="display: none;" data-label="test">blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Tabs code as below:

```
$(".jtab").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.jtab').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(this).closest('.jtabcontainer').find('.jtabsection').hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    return false;
});
```

And the clone code:

```
var emptyBuild = [];
$(".jsection").each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('id') !== "basicdata"){
        var tabName = $(this).attr('id');
        emptyBuild[tabName] = [];
        emptyBuild[tabName]['jtab'] = $(this).find(".jtab").clone();
        emptyBuild[tabName]['jtabsection'] = $(this).find(".jtabsection").clone();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', ".jbadd", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    var sectionid = $(this).parents('.jgridcontainer').attr('id');
    if(sectionid == "HDRTAB"){
        var newtabName = $(this).parents(".jgridrow").find("[data-label='Tab Name']").val();
        var newtablink = emptyBuild['headerfields']['jtab'];
        var newtabsection = emptyBuild['headerfields']['jtabsection'];
        $('#headerfields').find('.jtab').removeClass('active');
        newtablink.find('a').attr("href","#"+newtabName).html(newtabName);
        newtabsection.attr('id',newtabName).attr('data-label',newtabName).find('.lgndmaster').html(newtabName);
        $('#headerfields').find('.jtablink').append(newtablink);
        $('#headerfields').find('.jtabcontainer').append(newtabsection);
    }        
});
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Even the tab that was cloned from does not respond to clicks. The new tab content does not open, nor is it being set active on click.

Note: This is NOT JQuery-UI tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding tabs `dynamically` you need to do `event delegation` here which you have already written for `.jbadd`. So change your `event` of handling `click` on tabs as follows:

```
$(document).on('click','.jtab',function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.jtab').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(this).closest('.jtabcontainer').find('.jtabsection').hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)